# Ember Data: model.get('modelName') is undefined, but model._internalModel works

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data 2.2.0 and Ember 2.2.1. After retrieving a model from the data store, I'd like to get the model's type name as a string.

According to the API Docs, DS.Model defines a [modelName](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_modelName)  property, which looks like what I want. However, I find that `model.modelName`, and `model.get('modelName')`are undefined, after retrieving `model` from the store with `findRecord`.

On the other hand, `model._internalModel.modelName` returns the lowercased, dasherized name of the model, as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: You will have to use: `model.get('constructor.modelName')` to achieve what you want.
Also, in the docs `modalName` is the attribute of `store` class rather than a record. So the unexpected behaviour. See the example in docs for clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like a slight ambiguity in the documentation. It doesn't help that the `modelName` example uses `DS.Store#modelFor` which could be confused with `Ember.Route#modelFor`.

`DS.Store#modelFor` returns, according to the documentation, "a model class for a particular key. Used by methods that take a type key (like find, createRecord, etc.)". What I understand by this is that it returns the actual `DS.Model` class, and not the instance. `_internalModel` also returns the `DS.Model` class, hence the same behaviour.

I believe the safer alternative is doing `model.constructor.modelName`.

Comment: That's helpful! `model.constructor.modelName` is what I need. Maybe there's something I'm missing, but from playing around in my console, it looks like `model._internalModel` still has data specific to the instance, e.g. `id` and `record`... it appears to be an instance rather than a class.